# How to use different model in same view in mvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[My Main View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0ca3.jpg)

This is my view . if i open this view it want to load  all the list  of  data which is mention in the below  image   eg

[List of data to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ovf9.jpg)

But the properties of   FromDate ,ToDate and VisitingDate,CustomerName,EmployeemPurpose of visit ,ContactPerson Email are in different models.

**My VisitorsViewModel model**

```
  public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
```

**My View_VisitorsForm Model**

```
  public System.Guid VisitingID { get; set; }
  public string Employee { get; set; }
  public string CustomerName { get; set; }
  public Nullable<System.DateTime> VisitingDate { get; set; }
  public string StartTime { get; set; }
  public string EndTime { get; set; }
  public string SpendTime { get; set; }
  public string POVisit { get; set; }
```

so i decided to access two model properties in same view so i call one model property in another model which is mentioned in the below model

**My VisitorsViewModel model**

```
  public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }

  public ICollection<View_VisitorsForm> Visits { get; set; }
```

**My controller code**

```
  public ActionResult displaycustomer()
  {
  List<View_VisitorsForm> objvisitlist = (from v in db.View_VisitorsForm select v).ToList();
  return View(objvisitlist);
  }
```

This is my  Controller code

```
   List<View_VisitorsForm> objvisitlist = (from v in db.View_VisitorsForm select v).ToList();
```

This is the query to list all the data.

**My view**

```
  @model Sample_Customer.View_VisitorsForm
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "DailyVisitReport";
  }

  <div class="text-center">
  <h2 style="color: #0000FF">Visit Report</h2>
  </div>
  <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Content/BootStrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Content/BootStrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.FromDate)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.FromDate,new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })

  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">

  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToDate)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text"})

 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-5">
 <div class="form-group">
 <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Ok" />
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th style="color: #1a1ae9">Visiting Date</th>
 <th style="color: #1a1ae9">Customer Name</th>
 <th style="color: #1a1ae9">Employee</th>
 <th style="color: #1a1ae9">Purpose of Visit</th>
 <th style="color: #1a1ae9">Contact Person</th>
 <th style="color: #1a1ae9">Description</th>
 <th style="color: #1a1ae9">Next Appointment</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
 @foreach (var i in Model.??)in this place ?? i donno which object i have to call here
 {
 <tr>
 <td>
 @Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:MMM-dd-yyyy}", i.VisitingDate))
 </td>
  <td>
  @i.CustomerName
  </td>
  <td>
 @i.Employee
  </td>
  <td>
 @i.POVisit
 </td>
 <td>
 @i.ContactPerson
 </td>
 <td>
 @i.Description
 </td>
  <td>
  @Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:MMM-dd-yyyy}", i.NextAppointment))
  </td>
  </tr>
   }
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

My doubt is  i call the one model (view_visitorsForm)  in VisitorsViewmodel by

```
 public ICollection<View_VisitorsForm> Visits { get; set; }
```

and i have to list all the data in view when i open the page .so  in controller i wrote this code

```
  List<View_VisitorsForm> objvisitlist = (from v in db.View_VisitorsForm select v).ToList();
```

Now i created the view by giving model name as **VisitorsViewModel**. Now my doubt is  which object  i have to call in the place of **??** (in the line of foreach).so it will display all the data when i open the page..

i tried to explain my issue as  per my level best please any one understand my issue and help me to solve this problem.

Advance thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are passing a *List* to the view so you can directly use *Model* itself in the for loop

Comment: that is only asking in the place of ?? @foreach (var i in Model.??) whixch object i have to use

Comment: Does this work *@foreach (var i in Model)* ?

Comment: no its is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you need to use multiple models in a `View`, it is advisable to create a wrapper `ViewModel` class. And you have done it correct by creating a `VisitorsViewModel`. However when you already have `VisitorsViewModel` model which has got the from and to date properties, you could also have an property of this class in your `VisitorsViewModel` but that's a separate thing.

Now back to your question, make sure that you have bind your `View` with `VisitorsViewModel` model.

And in your controller method, first create an instance of the model, initialize `Visits` property and pass it to view. Something like this -

```
    public ActionResult displaycustomer()
    {
        List<View_VisitorsForm> objvisitlist = (from v in db.View_VisitorsForm select v).ToList();

        VisitorsViewModel model = new VisitorsViewModel();
        model.Visits = objvisitlist; 

        return View(model);
    }
```

...and in your `View` you can access to this object like -

```
@foreach (var i in Model.Visits)
```

Comment: first of all i have to say thanks to you. the out put came which is shown in the below image  [Output][3]
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MdPxI.jpg but when  i open the page the data are visible in the two text boxes . i don't want that when  i open the view the two text boxes become empty..

Comment: @Susan - The date fields are binded to `dateTime` type, and if it do not have any value, it will show the default value. If you do not want that, either you should put some check in your view of declare the date fields nullable like - `public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }`

Comment: @Susan - Additionally in any case, you also need to initialize your from a nd to dates with appropriate values like - `model.FromDate = someDate` in you controller, and then pass it to view, which I have skipped in my answer.

Comment: yes Yogi now i want to do that i want to show the list as per selected date criteria but i wrote ajax call and get it through json but i donno how to return again it to view if you explain that also means it better me to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Tuple** like this..

```
@model Tuple<FirstModel, SecondModel>

<div> 
    @Model.Item1.FirstModelProp
    @Model.Item2.SecondModelProp
</div>
```

Comment: oh i donno about this way prashant but i  have a try.. but i got one doubt where i have to declare this line in top of the view

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model that contains both of your other models

Comment: yes i tried that too but in the place of ?? @foreach (var i in Model.??) which object i have to call so it will display all the data when i open the page the objvisitlist(in controller) or Visits(in model)

Comment: well I was gonna write code but @Yogi did it. it is the anwswer

Comment: ktt if i wrote the ajax code to send the from date and todate to controller and in controller get the date using json and i calculate the   var objVisitEntrycount = (from v in db.View_VisitorsForm
                                      where v.VisitingDate >= fromdate && v.VisitingDate <= todate
                                      select v).ToList();  list as per selected date criterial . Now my doubt is how to return again this object to view

Comment: meybe you can put an unique ID to this div ;

<div class="form-group" id="uniqueId">
  @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.FromDate)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.FromDate,new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
<label id="uniqueIdLabel"></label>
  </div>

then find this id in ajax on success function, put the count into uniqueIdLabel label


but before you do this check this article about ajax calls

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/795483/Do-GET-POST-PUT-DELETE-in-asp-net-MVC-with-Jquery

Comment: sorry for late response